# Does DEManager Form Cost a Super Message?

Tags: form

Thank you for the attention. First: does the forms of Web Collect, especially the DEManager, have a cost? Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5

I asked the support team, but they told me to talk with my commercial. And my commercial isn't a good professional, so I'm to understand better if there is a cost with DEManager. For example: 1 CloudPages Impression consumes 1 Super Message. The same happens with DEManager or not?

Others cost about the Super Message: https://a.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/www/ocms-backup/assets/pdf/misc/marketing_cloud_super_message_bundles.pdf

Thank you!